# Adding a new row to a dataframe - why .loc[len(df)] instead of .iloc[len(df)]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Let's say that we're given a simple pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [4,5,6]})
```

I would like to append a new row to this dataframe. Why doesn't the following approach work?

```
df.iloc[len(df)]=[9,9]
```

Interestingly, it all works normally if we use `.loc[]` instead, even though `len(df)` is an integer and `.iloc[]` is used for integer-location based indexing, unlike `.loc[]`.

Comment: iloc stand for integer location, since you are trying to add a row to the dataframe that isn't already existing iloc is giving you and indexer out-of-bound IndexError.  Where as .loc will create an "index label" with the value of the len(df) then assign values to those dataframe columns at that index.  iloc can't assign because iloc doesn't really know the proper "label" to give that index.

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply! :)

Answer (score 5):

You are using index assign, which is `loc` not `iloc`  From the doc *.iloc will raise IndexError if a requested indexer is out-of-bounds*

```
df.loc[len(df)]=[9,9]
df
Out[349]: 
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  9  9
```